# Performing a right outer join with a group by using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am having trouble designing a linq query designed to find the number of active users for a particular month.

Here are my classes:

```
public class Reg_User
{
    int userID { get; set; }          
    DateTime dateStart { get; set; }
}


public class Reg_User_Log
{
    int userID { get; set; }
    DateTime dateModified { get; set; }
    bool deactivationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

A Reg_User_Log record is created only when an account is deactivated or reactivated, so new accounts will have no associated logs.

The user will specify a month and year which we will call specifiedDate, and I need to find users who have a dateStart time prior to the specified time who have no log files, in addition to those who's most recent log file that is prior to the specified month and year has a deactivationStatus value of false.

The sql query I made to do this is as follows:

```
SELECT 
   usr.id
  ,max([dateModified]) as 'last modified date'
  ,(select deactivationStatus from tbl_reg_user_log ilg where userid = usr.id and dateModified = max(lg.datemodified))
  FROM [IO].[dbo].[tbl_reg_user_log] lg
right outer join tbl_reg_user usr on lg.userID = usr.id
  where usr.clientid = specifiedID and (lg.dateModified <= specifiedDate or lg.dateModified is null) and date_Start <= specifiedDate
  group by usr.id
```

This query does not account for logs that have a deactivation status of true - I haven't figured that part out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I ended up solving this by going ahead and breaking it into two separate linq queries.

temp in this is a DateTime of the first day of the next month

```
//Obtains all users who have never been deactivated and were created prior to the month in question
newRecord.TotalUsers = (from usr in db.tbl_Reg_User
                        join lg in db.tbl_reg_user_log on new { UserID = usr.ID } equals new { UserID = lg.userID } into lg_join
                        from lg in lg_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where (usr.date_Start < temp) && usr.clientID == j.clientID && usr.clientID != 1
                        where lg.dateModified == null
                        select usr.ID).Count();

//Obtains users who were deactivated at some point but were reactivated prior or during the month in question
newRecord.TotalUsers += (from usr in db.tbl_Reg_User
                            join lg in db.tbl_reg_user_log on new { UserID = usr.ID } equals new { UserID = lg.userID } into lg_join
                            from lg in lg_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (usr.date_Start < temp) && usr.clientID == j.clientID && usr.clientID != 1
                            where lg.dateModified != null && lg.dateModified < temp
                            orderby lg.dateModified descending
                            group lg by lg.userID into g
                            select g).Select(x => x.Where(y => y.deactivationStatus != true)).Count();
```